# hosts file windows server 2008

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, localhost, host

I am trying to change the entry in HOST file windows 2008 server so that I can host multiple user friendly website for learning purpose.

Find attached an image of my host file and IIS setting. Both "Site1.com" and "Default Web site" point to same folder "wwwroot". But if I type "http:www.site1.com or http://site1.com" will not display anything on browser. Instead if I type http://localhost, the browser displays the default IIS7 html page. How to fix so that I can type site1.com and display II7 default page.[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you added for Host Name when editing the bindings for the second web site ("site1.com")?

Comment: Its set as www.site1.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the Host Name for the Site1.com site to accept requests for www.site1.com also make sure that site1.com is bound to port 80. Select Bindings... from the Actions/Edit Site section of IIS Manager for the site. You settings should look like the following:

[image]

**Update:** Just noticed that you have your host files entries commented out... Remove the # from the beginning of the lines for www.site1.com and it should work...

Comment: It is set like this ...!!!!

Comment: Thanks for confirming the bindings. Please see update... I believe the issue is related to your hosts file.